# Randomly choose one cell from the grid and mark until some condition happen

Tags: algorithm, matrix, shuffle

I have `NxN` boolean matrix, all elements of which have initial state `false`

```
bool[][] matrix = GetMatrix(N);
```

In each step of the loop, I want to choose one cell (`row i, column j`) uniformly at random among all `false` cells, and set it to `true` until some condition happen.

Which method to use? I have this two ways in mind.

- Create a `NxN` array from `0...(NxN-1)`, shuffle using uniformly shuffling algorithm than sequentially take i element from this array and set matrix[i/N][i%N].

Uses `O(N^2)` additional memory, and initialization take `O(N^2)` time

And second

- Generate random `i` from `0...(N^2-1)` and if (i/N, i%N) is set in matrix, repeat random generation until founding unset element.

This way doesn't use any additional memory, but I have a difficulty to estimate performance... can it be a case, when all elements except one are set, and random repeats a lot of times looking for free cell? Am I right, that as soon as random theoretically works uniformly, this case should not happen so often?

Comment: @Save In an NxN matrix, there are N^2 elements, thus linear time (which Fisher-Yates is) implies O(N^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to reply to your questions, with a worst case scenario anaysis that happens when, as you have pointed out, all cells but one are taken.

Let's start by noting that `p = P(X = m) = 1/N^2` . From this, we obtain that the probability that you'll have to wait  `k` tosses before getting the desired result is `P( Y = k) = p * (1-p)^(k-1)` . This means that, for `N = 10` you will need 67 random numbers to have a probability greater than 50% to get yours, and 457 to have a probability greater than 99%.

The general formula that gives you the number `k` of tosses needed to get the a probaiblity greater than `alpha` to get your value is:

```
k > (log(1 - alpha) / log(1-p)) -1
```

where `p` is define as above, equal to `1/N^2`

That could get much worse with N getting bigger. You could think about creating a list of the indices you need and get one randomly for it.

Comment: but did you consider fact, that if rand returns 1 for the first time, in the second run the probability of returning 1 is less than 1/N^2 but more less, because it suppose to work uniformly?

Comment: IF we assume that we are generating random numbers, we must also assume that the past doesn't count. If i toss a coin 100 times and i always get head, the probability that on the 101th toss i'll get head is still 0.5. Uniformity comes in the long run, that is, assuming we have an infinity sequence of numbers.

Comment: That's true @Save, but in programming there are no completely random numbers right? there are pseudo-random numbers.. I think this make sense, am I right?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt You areright, but even with them, if in the first draft we get a 1, the probability to get a one in the second one is still the same :) The fact that they are pseudo it means that they are not really "random", not that getting 100 random numbers between 1 and 100 we'll get a permutation of the integers in the [1,100] range

Comment: In programming random take some seed(probably time tick by default) and calculates next number with some formula on next run... so I think no, the second time probability of getting 1 is more more less... in c# example here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx the array return by getnextbytes have almost no duplicates...

Comment: You know we can't take 2 runs of an algorithm and infer over it, right? :) and "so I think no, the second time probability of getting 1 is more more less" this would mean that, randoming numbers between 1 and 0, we should always get the alternating sequence 1010101010 or 01010101. IF what you are suggesting had to happen, it would screw most algoirthms based on random.

Comment: no, I don't say exactly that sequence, but if the first time we get 1, the probability we will get 1 for second time is about 40% less than 0, but 1 is also possible...I will check this... from my point of view, if we get two numbers, the amount of 0,0 and 1,1 will be about 40% less than the amount of 1,0 and 0,1... this is easy to check

Comment: Just be sure not to confuse the problem "what's the probability to get the same value twice given a random number generator" with *your* problem :) If you carefully read the wikipedia page on pseudorandom numbers, one of the properties most stressed out is that they must act just like "real" random sequences, and the "memory loss" ( aka what we have discussed up to now) is one of the required features of a random sequence.

Comment: I see now, thanks, you are right, sorry :) BTW I checked this for random pairs and this counts are almost the same tests.Where(t=>t[0]==t[1]).Count().Dump();
tests.Where(t=>t[0]!=t[1]).Count().Dump(); so you mean the first version is better right? it uses memory, but runs faster...

Comment: Yea, in my opinion if you have to chose between the two, go with the first one. If you don't need all the elements in the matrix, I think it's better, at every loop to create a list of avaible members of the matrix and pick one random from them. The space requirement is the same, but you should save in execution time.

Answer (score 1):

> Generate random i from 0...(N^2-1) and if (i/N, i%N) is set in matrix,
>   repeat random generation until founding unset element.

The analysis of this algorithm is the same as the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The running time is Theta(n^2 log n).